# How do I tell php to consider a string as an array / json

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a dynamic table that can be modified from an admin control panel and I'm storing the data in an array of arrays in a database column like this:

example:
    tableBody: [['test','test 2'],['1','2']]

then I want to output the table on the front-end like this:

```
<table>
    <?php 
        $arrayFromDB = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "select * from specialtable where id='$tableId'"))['tableBody'];
        $body = "";
        $tableArray = (how to convert to array this string $arrayFromDB);
        foreach ($tableArray as $key) {
            $body.= "<tr>";
            foreach ($key as $keyt) {
                $body.= "<td>".$keyt."</td>";
            }
            $body.="</tr>";
        }
        echo $body;
    ?>
</table>
```

SOLVED: 
the problem was the way I stored it was wrong. Basically I was storing in a custom way that is equivalent with json only that I was using ' instead of ".
Now I can just use `json_decode()`

Comment: if you have string in json format you can use json_decode , if you want to make a json format you can use json_encode.. There is a lot of info inside php.net about it

Comment: I tried with json_decode, but it didn't work, because I think it's not a json format. Can you tell me how this [['test','test 2'],['1','2']] should be in json format?

Comment: you should use json_encode(array()) before storing array in to database. then json_decode() will work straight away.

Comment: How did you initially build the string that contain the array you want to retrieve from the DB ?

Comment: Use either `serialize()` or `json_encode()` to store the value in your database, then `unseralize()` or `json_decode()` to use it after fetching from the database. The way it is stored right now, that string is neither JSON nor serialized array, you'd need a custom function to parse it.

Comment: So I'm using a plugin that gives me the data in json then I do this: $bodyjson = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['body']));
  $body= "[";
  foreach ($bodyjson as $key) {
   $body .= "[";
   foreach ($key as $keyt) {
    $body .= "'".$keyt."',";
   }
   $body .= "],";
  }
  $body .="]";
  $body = str_replace(",]", "]", $body); 

Now that I think about it it's really stupid what I did, I should've stored just the json. I did it because the plugin requires this format [['test','test 2'],['1','2']] for modyfing afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, I think I got it now :)
Excuse my ignorance

Comment: opk so the problem was instead of this  [['test','test 2'],['1','2']] should be [["test","test2"],["1","2"]] with ", not '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store your array to string in mysql DB using below php function.

```
//for eg Define array 
$array = array();
$array[0][] = 'test';
$array[0][] = test 2;
$array[1][] = 'test';
$array[1][] = test 2;
// convert array to json
json_encode($array);
```

Now when you retrieve that data from mysql database just decode that string.

```
$arrayFromDB = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "select * from specialtable where id='$tableId'"))['tableBody'];
$decodedStrArray = json_decode($arrayFromDB);
```

Its your decode Array...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already solved my problem, *see edited post* :)

Comment: sorry i didnt see comments. useful for others.